# Minikube start on Mac throws certificate error when using hyperkit driver

Tags: macos, virtualbox, minikube

I am getting below error when I try to start a minikube on my Mac.

Command : `minikube start`

> invalid configuration: [unable to read client-cert
> /Users/sathishkumar/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt for
> minikube due to open
> /Users/sathishkumar/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt: no such
> file or directory, unable to read client-key
> /Users/sathishkumar/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key for
> minikube due to open
> /Users/sathishkumar/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key: no such
> file or directory]

What is the solution to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

And it's working.

Answer (score 5):

Try to delete and restart clean minikube. To do so, follow this process:

Delete the minikube cluster (ignore this step if this gives the same error).

```
$ minikube delete
```

Now delete the `.minikube` folder,

```
$ rm -rf $HOME/.minikube
```

Now, start the minikube again:

```
$ minikube start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
minikube start --embed-certs
```

for your original issue as minikube puts the certs externally to the kubeconfig by default. Using `--embed-certs` inlines them in the config like Docker Desktop & KinD do.